# Configure Jersey 2 web.xml for Swagger/ OpenAPI v3

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, openapi, swagger-2.0

I am running a Jersey 2.30.1 API and I want to upgrade the Swagger documentation to OpenAPI v3.

My new swagger dependencies in the pom.xml look like this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.17.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Previously (swagger 1.5 with swagger-ui 2.2.10-1), I had Swagger configured in my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
            <servlet-name>Jersey2Config</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>io.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>api.version</param-name>
                <param-value>2.0</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
                <param-value>/api</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>4</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I would like to do the same now, but I can't find a documentation, if and how that would be possible.

How can I define the swagger base path and API version in my web.xml with OpenAPI v3?

Comment: FWIW, I'm running into the same problem. Please let us know if you found a solution for this

Comment: @RvPr I've added an answer which you might want to review to see if it is relevant to you.

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with this, my solution is basically like so.

**pom.xml:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.52.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.10</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.10</version>
</dependency>
```

**web.xml:**

The Jersey2Config servlet is completely removed from web.xml.
The servlet configuration needs to be changed for the parameter `io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2.integration.resources`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>my servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>my.package.to.scan, io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2.integration.resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
```

Additional to web.xml a new file openapi.yaml has to be created under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`. This is responsible for creating the openapi.yaml/ openapi.json file which will be consumed by the swagger ui.

**openapi.yaml:**

```
prettyPrint: true
cacheTTL: 0
readAllResources: false /** Only show methods in swagger-ui that are annotated */
openAPI:
  info:
    version: '1.0'
    title: 'my application'
  servers:
    - url: '/my-application'
```

**swagger ui:**

```
...
window.onload = function() {

    const window.ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
        url: 'https://my-domain.com/my-application/openapi.json',
        dom_id: '#swagger-ui-container',
        docExpansion: 'none',
        defaultModelsExpandDepth: -1,
        deepLinking: true,
        presets: [
          SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
          SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
        ],
        plugins: [
          SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
        ],
        layout: "StandaloneLayout",
        apisSorter: "alpha",
        tagsSorter: "alpha",
        operationsSorter: "alpha",
        validatorUrl: null
      });
}
...
```